# Attribute Values not showing when running a query

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, query, spatial-query

The attribute values are not displayed for the 'Model Number' field when running a query yet the attributes are stored in the attribute table(When I say all unique, nothing comes up)!!

[image]

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: QGIS 3.2.0. Thing is, I imported the CSV file. When I save the CSV as a shp. file, I am able to see the attributes for the 'Model Number' in the query and label field. However, when I import is as a GeoPackage, the attributes for the 'Model Number' doesn't show up when I want to run a query.. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: What does the error message say? That it cannot find the field? This could be a bug.

Comment: There is no Error message that pops up. It just doesn't display the attributes for 'Model Number' when I click on 'all Unique/ 10 samples' in the Select by expression Tool. This only happens when I import the shapefile to GeoPackage.

Comment: I meant when you click the blue text where it says `Output preview`, it should give a message :)

Comment: The expression is invalid as it is incomplete. It is supposed to be ' Model Number = MA5608T V800' but since the attributes for Model Number doesn't want to show up, then I cant get any model number to complete the expression. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: I tried to duplicate your issue with a different CSV, but had no problem. I created a CSV, imported it and exported it as a geopackage. The attribute values load properly in the "select by expression" expression builder.

Comment: Can you share your CSV? Maybe the issue is specific to your file.

Comment: I managed to do it. It appears that the 'Model Number' Field did not have an underscore in the title name. So the query expression did not recognize it and therefore did not show its attributes.When I added the underscore, all worked perfectly!!!